# I'm using Caps Lock as the Compose key. How can I still get caps lock behavior?

Tags: wayland, capslock, compose-key

I'm running Ubuntu 23.04 with Wayland.

I've set the Compose Key to be Caps Lock in the Keyboard settings dialog.  That's convenient - I can now compose lots of fancy characters easily.  (For various reasons, none of the other compose key options will work for me - Alt/Ctrl would interfere with application shortcuts, I don't have a Right Super, Menu, or Scroll Lock key on my notebook, and Print Screen is hard to reach.)

However, I would still like to be able to use caps lock behavior occasionally, when I actually want to type something IN CAPITAL LETTERS.  So ideally I'd like to be able to type e.g. Shift+Caps Lock or Ctrl+Caps Lock to enable this behavior.  Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a possibility, but it has a little drawback.

- Install Gnome Tweaks
- In the "Keyboard & Mouse" tab, click "Additional Layout Options"
- Under "Caps Lock behavior", enable "Make Caps Lock an additional Esc, but Shift + Caps Lock is the regular Caps Lock".

The drawback is that hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to turn Capslock on also start a compose key sequence.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I tried this and it works!  You're right that Shift+CapsLock also starts a compose sequence, so I have to type e.g. "Shift+CapsLock Backspace" to cancel the compose sequence while remaining in caps lock mode.  But I can get used to that easily, so basically this solves my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution stopped working for me after a week or so - I'm not sure why.  I've since realized that there are better Compose key alternatives - right Alt doesn't conflict with too many shortcuts, or I can use Scroll Lock or the menu key since there are actually ways to type those on my notebook keyboard.